# www to non www redirecting issue

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using `.htaccess` to redirect from `www.test123.com` to non `http://test123.com` site. 
Because it cause the cross domain issue in `Ajax`.
I am not able to use `www.test123.com` in Ajax(returns 500 error).

So, i used this code in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

And all thing is working great.
Now issue is, i have unity app which calling php file like this

```
http://www.test123.com/save.php
```

And posting some variables with this URL also.
so i am not able to get that post data because this will redirect from `www.test123.com` to `http://test123.com`. So i lost post data.
What should i do to get my post data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ignore `POST` method from your redirect rule as `POST` data does get lost while doing a full redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```